# How to use drush config:set for translations?

Tags: 8, drush

https://drushcommands.com/drush-9x/config/config:set/

For one language site the command is:

```
drush config:set system.site name "Drupal 8 English sitename"
```

But how to be, if the site is multilanguage, at example two languages?
Example:

- English site name: "Drupal 8 English sitename"
- Italian site name: "Drupal 8 Italian sitename"

At example for site settings in web interface I can translate it in tab "Translate system information" http://take.ms/i9jUN.
But how to set translated config value with drush? It is possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For getting the site name in Spanish for example it's

```
drush config:get language.es:system.site name
```

Unfortunately the following doesn't work and I wonder if this is a bug or what's missing.

```
drush -y config:set language.es:system.site name "Hello World"
```

This just gives me

> `Invalid character in Config object name language.es:system.site.`

Will update answer later.

---

Created an issue on drupal.org: [drush config:set for other than default collections raises exception](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3011276). Where I also provided a patch you may use if you are really in need right now.

Comment: I have the same error: "Invalid character..."

Comment: @Viktor – Answer updated. I created an issue and provided a patch on drupal.org. Use it with caution. :)

Comment: `drush -y config:set language.es.system.site name "Hello World"` also works

Comment: @SbonisoMarcusNzimande – Unfortunately I can't confirm that. All I get is *Config language.es.system.site does not exist*. Which version of Drupal and Drush were you using?