# drush config-status on translation / language config files?

Tags: 8, drush, configuration

Similar with but not the same as [How to use drush config:set for translations?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/271984/how-to-use-drush-configset-for-translations), is there a way to scan for a site's language config changes via drush or so?

I have a lot of sites on the same server (multi-site), and I would rather check on this via a drush command than having to log in each of the sites to look at the output of `/admin/config/development/configuration`.

For normal config changes I could run `drush cst | config-status` but this doesn't appear to work for language config and puts the site at risk of accidentally wiped out language config when not captured.

**Example:**

[image: configuration screen]

```
$ drush cst -- returns nothing
```

```
$ drush cget language.fr:block.block.claro_breadcrumbs
settings:
  label: 'Breadcrumbs FR'
```

Comment: AFAIK, everything shown on `/admin/config/development/configuration` IS shown in `drush cst`.  If you are talking about the translations that can be exported to `.po` files, those won't be shown by Drush, but those aren't affected by configuration import/export either.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `config-status` command doesn't show the config's relevant collection, which is how I got confused, but @Patrick Kenny is right, the output does list the language config files.

One solution would be to create a custom drush command similar to `Drush\Drupal\Commands\config\ConfigCommands`, and alternatively `config-import` does highlight the collection. So one can run `drush cim | config-import` without proceeding after the confirmation prompt, so you don't lose the config:

```
$ drush cst -- does not show collection
------------------------------- ------------ 
 Name                            State       
------------------------------- ------------ 
 block.block.claro_breadcrumbs   Only in DB 
------------------------------- ------------
```

```
$ drush cim -- does show collection
+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+
| Collection  | Config                        | Operation |
+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+
| language.fr | block.block.claro_breadcrumbs | Delete    |
+-------------+-------------------------------+-----------+

Import the listed configuration changes? (yes/no) [yes]:
```

Comment: `drush config:import --no` seems to do the trick